# jQuery, Looping through paragraphs and getting text

Tags: javascript, jquery

So basically with jQuery, I am trying to loop through 3 paragraphs containing tweets. The 3 paragraphs are all of class .tweet-text

For some reason, in the following code, $test2 will be set properly to the first tweet's text, but in the each loop, the js crashes whenver i try to set str. Why is this?

```
    var $tweets = $(".sidebar-tweet .tweet-text");
    var $test2 = $tweets.text();
    alert($test2);
    $tweets.each(function(i, $tweet){
        var str = $tweet.text();
        alert(str);
    });
```

I've been trying to debug this with Firebug but to no avail. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried using .innerHTML or something else besides .text()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $tweets = $(".sidebar-tweet .tweet-text");

        $tweets.each(function(i, current){
            var str = $(current).text();
            alert(str);
        });
```

The issue was that the current object is not by defalt a jquery object, you must wrap it $(current) ... to use the jquery methods

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
var str = $(this).text();
```

Comment: technically it should be `var str = $($tweet).text();` if we are to keep with his notation, shouldn't it?

Comment: @josh.trow if he wants, really badly, to follow the edict of using the parameter he supplied then I suppose you are correct ... but $(this) is the exact equivalent.

Comment: Yes, but as your answer originally stated, it would not work. I was commenting on how to make it work, not on his choice of variables.

Comment: @josh.trow   ahh. I shouldn't have used the term "won't work" I  meant that his version won't function properly at runtime since it was a dom object ... not a jquery object. =P

Answer (score 1):

Because `$tweet` will be a regular javascript object, not a jQuery object. You'll need to wrap it like:

```
var str = $($tweet).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to the `.each` method is not a jquery object, but the actual DOM element.

So you need to wrap it in jQuery again..

```
var $tweets = $(".sidebar-tweet .tweet-text");
var $test2 = $tweets.text();
alert($test2);
$tweets.each(function(i, tweet){
    var str = $(tweet).text();
    alert(str);
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/xjmZy/